# Does SQL Azure Data Sync conflicts get logged?

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization

I have successfully synced my SQL Azure DB with my on-premise DB. The log shows the following:

> Sync completed successfully in 1884.76 seconds.   Upload:   405323 changes applied    Download: 0 changes applied    For more information, provide tracing ID ‘xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx’ to customer support.

Does this mean there were no conflicts? Should there be any resolved conflicts, would they appear in the log?

Answer (score 1):

Resolving conflicts info won't appear on the portal. The "Sync completed successfully" indicates data synced and conflicts resolved if exist. If there are too much conflict rows, you will receive a warning message to tell you sync partially succeeded.